# Display more image like a GIF image in Android

Tags: android

I've problem which can't solved to complete my app.

I have 2 images ( 1 red, 1 green for example both in Assets folder). Now I want to display like 1 GIF image . That's mean first it show red image and then it show green, then continuous by red and repeat it for a long time until USER press Back Button on phone. Any solution for this? ( and if I have different folder with different number of images for each folder)

I already use Java library to display image from assets

Thank in advance!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html this should help you

Answer (score 1):

Use [AnimationDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html)

in drawable/green_red.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

in your activity

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.green_red);
animation = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
animation.start();
```

in your layout

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/green_red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/green_red"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically in you activity.

Like this-

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    boolean isGreen = true;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(isGreen)
            {
                isGreen = false;
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_image);

            }
            else
            {
                isGreen = true;
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_image);
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

Try this it will help you definitely.

Comment: Thank you, now it solve my problem but if I have 2 folder in Assets folder, one has 2 images and the other has 6 images. I use java library to display image from assets, can you give me some advice?
I have updated my question above.